# I dont understand why this infinite loop wont stop (React useEffect hook)

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import CardList from "./ClassList";
import { robots } from './Robots';
import { useState } from "react"; 
import './App.css'
const App = () =>{
    const [search , searchfun]  = useState('');
    const [robot ,setRobot] = useState(['']);


    // console.log(search);
    // searchfun=(event)=>{
    //     return event.target.value;
    // }
    console.log(robot)



    useEffect(()=>{
        setRobot(robots.filter((rob)=> rob.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())))
    }, [robot]);

    


    return(
    <div className="tc">
    <h1 className="f1">Robofriends</h1>
    <div>
            <input 
            className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
            type='search'
            placeholder='search robots' 
            onChange = {(event)=>{
                    searchfun(event.target.value);
                    
            }}

            />
            

        </div>
    <CardList robots={robot} />
    </div>

    );


}

export default App
```

Here when it enters the useffect function the robots value is set according to the search field(which initially is empty and all the data of the robots are included) . I have also given a dependency array of robot which wont change unless i input something into the search field ..but it keeps on rendering infinitely .

Can someone explain why this is happening

Comment: `[robot]` as last param in the `useEffect`, makes the useEffects execute every time `robot` change his value. And you are calling `setRobot` inside the useEffect, so you update the `robot` value, and the useEffects run again.  

Try initializing your robot state inside useState(<HERE>).

Don't use useEffect to initialize your state. Use `useState()` :)

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here

```
useEffect(()=>{
        setRobot(robots.filter((rob)=> rob.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())))
    }, [robot]);
```

try to change it in

```
useEffect(()=>{
        setRobot(robots.filter((rob)=> rob.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())))
    }, [search, robots]);
```

Comment: I updated my answer you can go with this

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to `setRobot` initially to the robots[] where it comes from  `'./Robots'`  and add the search to the deps useEffect

```
const [robot, setRobot] = useState(robots);
  useEffect(() => {
    setRobot(
      robot.filter(rob =>
        rob.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()),
      ),
    );
  }, [search]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of `robot` change when you run `setRobot`, not when you input something to search for

so yeah, that will result in an infinite loop